# How to add custom code to the 'Post' action from the GL Post Transactions screen

Tags: acumatica

I need to add custom code to the logic which posts transactions on the GL 'Post Transactions' screen.  After going through the T300 documentation and looking at the override of 'Release' to use as an example, I cannot find anything in the 'BatchPost' BLC that remotely resembles a posting process event/method that I can override.  Where would I find that logic and what's the best way to add my custom code to the Posting process, batch by batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to override posting process is to override `PX.Objects.GL.PostGraph.PostBatchProc(Batch b, bool createintercompany)`

All logic related to posting are located there.

Here is an example:

```
public class PostGraphExt : PXGraphExtension<PostGraph>
{
    public delegate Batch PostBatchProcDelegate(Batch b, bool createintercompany);
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual void PostBatchProc(Batch b, bool createintercompany, PostBatchProcDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        //your code here
        baseMethod(b, createintercompany);
        //or here
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw that - but I"m not sure of the syntax to override it or how to specify the delegate as in the T300 example for Release.  Do I use a [PXOverride] attribute?  Just a simple example would help.

Comment: Yes, in this case [PXOverride] attribute will help. I've updated answer with an example.